# Python выдает ошибку при работе с библиотекой psycopg2

Tags: python, sql

Я написал простой код, который добавляет в sql таблицу одну строку.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='avecoder', host='localhost', 
user='postgres', password='12345678')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('INSERT INTO name2 (name) VALUES ("Sasha")')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Но python выдает следующую ошибку:
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ОШИБКА:  столбец "Sasha" не существует

Что не так я написал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Для обозначения строк в SQL используются одинарные кавычки**

Замените

```
'INSERT INTO name2 (name) VALUES ("Sasha")'
```

На

```
"INSERT INTO name2 (name) VALUES ('Sasha')"
```

См [SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)